# Does accessing two different members of the same object need synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

If we have an object with two data members A, and B; Do we need any form of synchronization while accessing the two members from two different threads running in parallel? How about if the object was a global variable, versus the object was a heap object, accessed with a pointer to its address?

Edit:
Each thread reads and writes into only one distinct member, a one-to-one association, the number of threads is equal to the number of data members, and threads access them distinctly, until they finish and join the main thread.

Comment: Can you define what "accessing" means.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Accessing means all forms of accessing both reading and writing. I actually left it like that intentionally.

Comment: If "accessing" meant reading/loading, the answer would have been simple.  To clarify -- you are descibing a scenario where threads read and write to A, and also for B?

Comment: @DrewDormann Each thread reads and writes into only one member, a one-to-one association, the number of threads is equal to the number of data members, and accessed distinctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords you are looking for is [memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model).

Non-bitfield members are distinct memory locations; there is no race condition from reading/writing different members.

A write in one thread and access in another of the same memory location is a potential conflict.  Unless certain requirements are upheld (like *happens before*) this is a race condition, and your program has UB (undefined behaviour).

But access (read or write) to distinct members that are not bitfields won't trigger this.

The actual rules are more complex; not all bitfields share a memory location, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For a data-member that is accessed by only one thread, no synchronization is necessary.  For a data-member that might be written to by a thread, and *also* might be accessed (in any way) by any other thread, synchronization *is* necessary.

It doesn't make a difference whether the object is global or on the heap, except that objects on the heap might be deleted while other threads still hold a pointer to them -- e.g. if thread 1 deletes the object while thread 2 is (potentially) accessing one or more data-members in that object, you've got a problem, because thread 2 may try to read or write to the now-free-memory locations where the data member used to be located, invoking undefined behavior.  (You would typically avoid that problem by allocating the heap-object *before* creating the thread that will use it, and not deleting that heap-object until *after* that thread has exited and you've called `join()` on it to be sure it's gone)

Answer (score 1):

1.If you only read A and B from different threads, there is no synchronization
2.If some threads read AB and some threads write them, there should be synchronizing, here you can use two read/write locks to avoid affecing each other while access A or B. you can use [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)
to implement read/write lock